# customize filter options using php in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want only those filters to appear which has some products in it., for example if tops has only size L and M, then i want to display only L AND M filter option in size. same goes with other filters like category , brand name also. only those brand names which has products in it should be displayed. I want to write a php script for it. I am working on an android application which has magento back end.

Answer (score 0):

In **Admin** menu, open **Catalog** > **Attributes** > **Manage Attributes**. Find the attribute you want to show only with results and click on the row. In the form opened, scroll down for **Frontend Properties** tab change the value **Use In Layered Navigation** to **Filterable (with results)**.

Updated answer;

If you want don't want to change your attribute use in layered navigation to **Filterable (with results)** and filter only in a theme you need to make a couple edits on your template files.

In **catalog/layer/filter.phtml** remove the "**else**" section like below:

```
        <?php else: ?>
            <span>
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel(); ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                    <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
```

In **configurableswatches/catalog/layer/filter.phtml** add a line after **$_hasItems = ($_item->getCount() > 0);** like below:

```
    $_hasItems = ($_item->getCount() > 0);
    if(!$_hasItems) continue;
```

Comment: I need to write a php script for it so that i can return the list of available filters to android front end to display, It should be completely dynamic. Only filters with available products should show